# Tumblr API - can GET but not POST

Tags: javascript, http, oauth, tumblr, hello.js

I'm trying to create a page where users can log in with their tumblr account and fill out a form to post to their blog.

I'm using hello.js with the tumblr module.

I've modified the tumblr module demo and everything seems to be working in terms of logging in and authenticating. However, I'm unable to convince the API to let me use any OAUTH-restricted POST commands. GET commands, such as retrieving a user's followed blogs, work fine. But if I try something simple such as user/follow to follow a new blog, I get a "401 Not Authorized" response.

What could be causing OAUTH restricted GET commands to be working fine, but POST does not?

You can see my testing code live at http://www.jereddanielson.com/testing/tumblr/hello.js-master/demos/tumblr.html

Below is the pertinent javascript. I'm using the OAUTH proxy at https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/

```js
function login(network){
 hello( network ).login({scope: 'publish_actions, publish, post, post_actions, follow, follow_actions'}).then( function(r){
  // Get followed blogs
  hello(network).api({path: '/user/following', method: "get"}).then(function(p){
   console.log(p);
   console.log("Tried to retrieve followed blogs. Response status: " + p.meta.status + " " + p.meta.msg);
  });
  // Try to follow a blog
  hello(network).api({path: '/user/follow', method: "post", data: {url: "daily-fractal.tumblr.com"}}).then(function(p){
   console.log(p);
   console.log("Tried to follow a blog. Response status: " + p.meta.status + " " + p.meta.msg);
  });
 }, function(e){
  console.error(e);
 });
}

hello.init({
 'tumblr' : "bQpjOrKgIu9pWVann1HVOAoW6gOGNoSpcMXIpwjNqghUmkwvgt"
},
{
 redirect_uri:'../redirect.html',
 oauth_proxy: "https://auth-server.herokuapp.com/proxy"
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you use [tumblr.js](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.js)?

Comment: I believe tumblr.js is a node.js package for server side applications. I'm trying to keep everything client side (hence the OAUTH proxy) but either the tumblr API somehow blocks POST actions through a proxy or I'm doing something wrong.